# Add class attribute value through interpolation of boolean

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a simple Angular 2 app pulling values from a JSON API and outputting a HTML list of those values.  The idea eventually is to create a tree view from the results built up by progressive API calls as tree nodes are opened in the UI.  For now I'm keeping it simple though and just returning a simple JSON object like this:

```
[
    {"Id":1054,"Name":"Rugby League","HasChildren":true},
    {"Id":1056,"Name":"Football","HasChildren":false}
]
```

I have an Angular 2 Component which consumes the data, like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'content-list',
    template: `
        <ol class="tree">
            <li *ngFor="#contentNode of contentNodes" class="tree__branch">
                {{ contentNode.Name }}
            </li>
        </ol>
        <div class="error" *ngIf="errorMessage">{{errorMessage}}</div>
    `
})
```

It pulls the JSON data and maps to the HTML list, which outputs a populated `<ol>` in the browser.

What I want to do is set an *additional* class on the `<li>` element if the value of `HasChildren` from the JSON feed is `true`.

I thought it'd be possible just to interpolate the value like this:

```
<li *ngFor="#contentNode of contentNodes" class="tree__branch {{ contentNode.HasChildren ? "tree__branch--has-children" : "" }}">
```

However, this causes template compilation errors.

Can anyone suggest how to get this working?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html) is for:

```
<li *ngFor="#contentNode of contentNodes" 
    class="tree__branch"
    [ngClass]="{'tree__branch--has-children': contentNode.HasChildren}">
```

Comment: Thanks, but crucially this doesn't set an *additional* class, as required.

Comment: Yes, it does. It adds the class `tree__branch--has-children` if `HasChildren`is true, and doesn't if it's false.

Comment: My Bad!  Apologies JB, yes it does, you're right :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**[working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QSZv1L?p=preview)**

for more info on attr,class,style and other stuff, look at Cheat Sheet - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html

```
<li *ngFor="#contentNode of contentNodes"
    class="tree__branch" 
    [class.tree__branch--has-children]="contentNode.HasChildren">
                {{ contentNode.Name }}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, but crucially this doesn't set an *additional* class, as required.

Comment: what do you mean by that? have you checked my demo?

Comment: `tree__branch` is the class that is added/removed. If you want the class to be named `additional` instead then just change that part.

Comment: There should always be a class of `tree__branch` regardless of the value of `HasChildren`.  When `HasChildren` is `true` though, it needs to set an additional class, so the class attribute on those elements would read: `class="tree__branch tree__branch--has-children"`.

Comment: Then use `class="tree__branch" [class.tree__branch--has-children]="contentNode.HasChildren"`

Comment: Oh I just saw it. was away. Thanks Gunter !